# Trying to execute string returned from get request with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, server, scripting

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script do admin some features from my servers. I want the content of the script was loaded in a variable for execute after. The reason is I have several servers and I don't want enter one by one when I have to change something in the script.

I've thought return text script from a get request and then execute with &.
Here is the testings I'm doing:

```
$R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://www.goltratec.com/pruebas/powershell.php?a=1
$a = {$R.Content}
& $a
```

$R.content return "write-host 'hola desde web'"
If I do a $a.getType() I get is a ScriptBlock but when I do & $a I see in console

```
write-host 'hola desde web'
```

Instead of

```
hola desde web
```

However if I do

```
$b={write-host 'hola desde web'}
& $b
```

I can see

```
hola desde web
```

I have check too $a and $b are the same type.

What is happening?

Thanks..

Comment: The usual way to do this kind of thing is `Invoke-Expression`. However, seeing people execute arbitrary code from the web without even looking at it first makes my skin crawl. Don't do that. It's just as bad as Linux users running `curl ... | bash` without a second thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$a` just becomes a scriptblock with a string inside. You want:

```
$a = [scriptblock]::Create($R.Content)
```

Comment: That's working fine but I still can't understand why is not working if $a.getType() was  telling that it was a Scriptblock..